# Facebook review: iOS app marked as not available, but is public

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm trying to submit a combined Facebook/iOS app for review so it will appear in the Facebook app center. Both apps are live (soft-launch) and available to the public (we have a few thousand users)

Part of the process is to include details of the iOS app, so it can be downloaded and tested. I used the app store ID for the app in question (that's currently live and available for download). When I go to submit however, I get this error:

[image]

> Your iOS app must be available in United States, Japan, United
>   Kingdom, Russia, Brazil, Taiwan, Germany, France, Spain, India, Israel
>   or Turkey in order for our review team to download it from the Apple
>   App Store.

The thing is; the app currently *is* (only) in the France app store. The Facebook app is live and open to the public as well, so why can't I submit this? Am I missing something basic?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a link to your app? We just uses Apples API to check if your app is available in France.

Comment: You can find it here: https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/permut-fun-new-picture-quiz/id830388736 - both the facebook and iOS versions are live, and everything is linked properly (i.e. "Send to mobile" in the appcenter page works)

Comment: The Itunes API returns the right thing https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=830388736&country=fr . Please file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For info, it seems like the bug has been fixed: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1478344835733264 (it also had a duplicate here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/789383024414348/)